# Using VBA, how do I create a custom field in Word that uses the current page number?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to add a custom field in Word (in the shape { CUSTOM_FIELD } ) that uses the current page number and outputs its text representation (12 => twelve), but in multiple exotic (not supported) languages, which is why the built-in English variant (page * cardtext) isn't sufficient.

The VBA code won't be a problem, but I need to know how to create a custom field.

The field would be added to the footer template, before 100s of pages would be added programmatically.

I tried using a custom DocProperty, but wasn't able to find a way to integrate the needed behavior. Another linked answer seems to be using the existing { PAGE } field, which wouldn't help, as I need to insert the new field (once only) into the footer template.

Comment: Before getting into vba, find out the construction of the field. It would start with the Page field. Try { Page \* cardtext }. Does that do what you want? I recommend asking about that in the forum http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/ with a link noting you also asked here.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon "but in multiple languages, which is why the built-in English variant isn't sufficient"

Comment: I have not tried it, which is why I suggested that you try it. I do not know what the CardText switch does in different languages. I do not know that it is applicable only to English. Again, ask what field structure will do this in a general Word forum. Once you have the field, then worry about the vba to create it. In general Word, it could also be saved as AutoText and inserted via vba from the AutoText.

Comment: Even edited, you question fails to clarify what you are trying to achieve or why you assert the CardText switch is insufficient. a PAGE field coded as {PAGE \\* CardText} will output a page # in the text of whatever the proofing language is.

Comment: Really? I say, I need a VBA-based solution and CardText won't work for me and that should be enough. I want to use a minor dialect of Basque-Algonquian Pidgin, there's no Office language pack for that.

Comment: @AlexanderH.Stebner How are you going to determine what language you want the field's result to show? Can you specify a "highest page number" that the field needs to work with?

Comment: @AlexanderH.Stebner - that additional information should have been in your question, not belatedly added to a comment. Without it, the question lacks crucial detail needed for an answer.

Comment: The question was just fine, you just insisted on me explaining why a related solution wouldn't work, although I've excluded it from being relevant. I mentioned the desired result only for ease of understanding not to have my  desired approach be dismissed outright.

Comment: No-one dismissed anything. Your obscure question made answering it impossible. Even the answer you accepted relied on your belated clarification. Moreover, it's hardly surprising MS doesn't support a language last used in the early 1700s. And no-one here is likely to know what the Basque-Algonquian Pidgin numbering is to develop a language-specific solution for it. Moreover, even with the use of DOCVARIABLES, you're still likely to require compound field coding to parse numbers by order of magnitude, which is part of what the field coding I posted demonstrates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't the only possible way to do this, but if you have a reasonably small maximum page count then you could use a { DOCVARIABLE } field something like this, where "LANG" is just a piece of text that identifies the language you want to use:

```
{ DOCVARIABLE "LANG{ PAGE }" }
```

You would then need to use VBA to set up 1 Document variable to store the text verion of each page number. Document variables are in essence key-value pairs stored invisibly in the document.

e.g. Let's suppose you were wanted the text versions of numbers from one to three in English, French and German. So you could have document variables with the following names and values

```
EN1  One
EN2  Two
EN3  Three
FR1  Un
FR2  Deux
FR3  Trois
DE1  Ein
DE2  Zwei
DE3  Drei
```

Even if you need hundreds or thousands of these, the amount of text you can store in Document variables is very large. OTOH if you need to be able to generate the texts dynamically by building them using an algorothm (as `\* Cardtext` probably does) this won't work.

To set up one of these variables youjust need, e.g.

```
ActiveDocument.Variables("EN1").Value = "One"
```

The field you would need for the English results would be

```
{ DOCVARIABLE "EN{ PAGE }" }
```

As long as you only need to use one language in each document, you could just change the "EN" to "FR" to get the French version, etc. - after all, if you only have one footer layout, you would only need to make one change. Otherwise, you could consider storing the language code somewhere else in the document, e.g.

- in a bookmark called LANG, in which case you might use

  { DOCVARIABLE "{ LANG }{ PAGE }" }
- in a DOCVARIABLE called LANG, so you would use

  { DOCVARIABLE "{ DOCVARIABLE LANG }{ PAGE }" }
- in a Custom document property called LANG, so you would use

  { DOCVARIABLE "{ DOCPROPERTY LANG }{ PAGE }" }

(The problem with using custom document properties for your numbers is that you can only have a small number of them).

If that general approach can't be made to fit what you're trying to achieve, I think you'll probably need to clarify your Question some more.

Comment: Sounds great. It will be one exotic language per document (using LANG would therefore work) and about 200+ pages. I can scriptedly create the list of var definitions, so the amount wouldn't be an issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

### The Cardtext switch will give numbering in different languages, assuming that the language is applied to the text as proofing language.

[image]

I would recommend saving a { Page * Cardtext } field as AutoText or another Building Block in your template and using code to insert it. Here is [my writing on using vba to insert AutoText](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#UsingVBABuildingBlock).

The following creates the field at the insertion point.

```
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, _
    PreserveFormatting:=False
Selection.TypeText Text:="Page \* CardText"
```

Comment: this will not work for my use-case. See edited question for clarification.

Comment: You can set the proofing language **for the field** in your vba. You can use templates with particular language settings in the styles. Here are my articles on the Microsoft site about using vba to change proofing language in styles. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/using-styles-for-proofing-language-settings/0a1bbf21-eaac-4044-afe6-253bfc47d65f https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/proofing-language-keeps-changing-solutions-how-can/c6483d0c-6fe3-41bf-8464-25535d3ec15b

Answer (score -1):

Now that you've explained what you're trying to do, here's how it can be done *without VBA*, for up to 999 pages, using a compound field coded as:

{QUOTE "{=MOD(INT({PAGE}/100),10) # "'{=INT((MOD(INT({PAGE}/100),10)-1)/3)-1 # "'{=MOD(MOD(INT({PAGE}/100),10)-1,9)-7 # "'Novecientos';'Sietientos';' Ochocientos'"}';'{=MOD(MOD(INT({PAGE}/100),10)-1,9)-1 # "'Trescientos';'{=MOD({PAGE},100) # "'Ciento';;'Cien'"}';'Doscientos'"}';'{=MOD(MOD(INT({PAGE}/100),10)-1,9)-4 # "'Seisientos';'Cuatroscientos';'Quinientos'"}'"}{=MOD({PAGE},100) # "' ';;"}';;''"}{=INT((MOD({PAGE},100)+10)/20)-1 # "'{=MOD(INT({PAGE}/10),10) # "'{=INT((MOD(INT({PAGE}/10),10)-1)/3)-1 # "'{=MOD(MOD(INT({PAGE}/10),10)-1,9)-7 # "'Noventa';'Setenta';'Ochenta'"}';'{=MOD(MOD(INT({PAGE}/10),10)-1,9)-1 # "'Treinta';'';''"}';'{=MOD(MOD(INT({PAGE}/10),10)-1,9)-4 # "'Sesenta';'Cuarenta';'Cincuenta'"}'"}';;''"}{=MOD({PAGE},10) # "'{=INT((MOD({PAGE},10)-1)/3)-1 # "'{=MOD(MOD({PAGE},10)-1,9)-7 # "' y Nueve';' y Siete';' y Ocho'"}';'{=MOD(MOD({PAGE},10)-1,9)-1 # "' y Tres';' y Uno';' y Dos'"}';'{=MOD(MOD({PAGE},10)-1,9)-4 # "' y Seis';' y Cuatro';' y Cinco'"}'"}';;"}';'{=INT((MOD({PAGE},100)+10)/20)-1 # "'';'{=MOD({PAGE},10) # "'{=INT((MOD({PAGE},10)-1)/3)-1 # "'{=MOD(MOD({PAGE},10)-1,9)-7 # "'Nueve';'Siete';'Ocho'"}';'{=MOD(MOD({PAGE},10)-1,9)-1 # "'Tres';'Uno';'Dos'"}';'{=MOD(MOD({PAGE},10)-1,9)-4 # "'Seis';'Cuatro';'Cinco'"}'"}';;"}';''"}';'{=INT(MOD({PAGE},100)/10)-1 # "'{=MOD({PAGE},10) # "'{=INT((MOD({PAGE},10)-1)/3)-1 # "'{=MOD(MOD({PAGE},10)-1,9)-7 # "'Veintinueve';'Veintisiete';'Veintiocho'"}';'{=MOD(MOD({PAGE},10)-1,9)-1 # "'Veintitrés';'Veintiuno';'Veintidós'"}';'{=MOD(MOD({PAGE},10)-1,9)-4 # "'Veintiséis';'Veinticuatro';'Veinticinco'"}'"}';;'Veinte'}';;'{=MOD({PAGE},10) # "'{=INT((MOD({PAGE},10)-1)/3)-1 # "'{=MOD(MOD({PAGE},10)-1,9)-7 # "'Diecinueve';'Diecisiete';'Dieciocho'"}';'{=MOD(MOD({PAGE},10)-1,9)-1 # "'Trece';'Once';'Doce'"}';'{=MOD(MOD({PAGE},10)-1,9) -4 # "'Dieciséis';'Catorce';'Quince'"}'"}';;'Diez'"}'"}'"}"}

As coded, the page #s are output in standard Spanish text - just as an example of what can be done. I'll leave it to you to edit the text to match the Basque-Algonquian Pidgin dialect. Note that the outputs for pages 1-9 are specified twice in the field code - once for digits below 10 and once for digits above 30 (with ' y ').

As Cherles Kenyon has already pointed out, for most languages all you need do is set the proofing language setting and employ a *\CardText switch. By using a single Custom Document Property (for which no VBA code is needed), you could wrap a series of such fields in an IF test that tests the Document Property's text. For example:

- {IF{DOCPROPERTY Lang}= "Basque-Algonquian" "Field code for
  Basque-Algonquian"}
- {IF{DOCPROPERTY Lang}= "Exotic Language A" "Field code for Exotic Language A"}
- etc.

The above field coding assumes you're using a system with English-language regional settings. For use with other language regional settings you'll need to replace the commas with semi-colons and the semi-colons with commas.

For a macro to convert the above into a working field, see *Convert Text Representations of Fields to Working Fields* in the **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** page at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html